# How to calibrate magnetic sensors using Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sensors, compass, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini with Cyanogenmod (11) and want to calibrate the compass / magnetic sensors.

With the stock rom this was possible by "dialing" `*#0*#`. This is however not implemented in Cyanogenmod.

How can I calibrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

1. Try to stay away from magnetic fields as far as you can
2. Open [GPS Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mictale.gpsessentials) and tap on compass (calibration will not work when the compass is not showing)
3. Put the phone on a flat surface with the display pointing up
4. Move the phone slowly, 5 seconds per full rotation is ok
5. Rotate the phone three full cycles around the axis pointing upward
6. Rotate the phone three full cycles around the axis pointing away from you
7. Rotate the phone three full cycles around the axis pointing right
8. The direction of rotation doesn't matter

This should fix your problem.

Credit to [lepidas](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4243808) on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1778131)

Comment: I tried it and it did something (much closer to north now). Results are however still inconsistent (direction of north varies by up to 90°). It would be nice to have an app that notifies me once the calibration was succesful.